# Date from String with .medium Format

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate, nsdateformatter

I have a date on a UITextField represented by its .medium formatter style (e.g. Mar 14, 2017), that I want to turn back into date.

I know that if I have the correct format, I can do so, but since I didn't use a literal string as the format, I have a little trouble with the conversion.

I am trying:

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateFormat = 
       //[NEED FORMAT STRING HERE]
calendarPicker.startDate = formatter.date(from: t3.text!)
```

But I have found no way to turn the .medium style into a string to reformat the string into a date.

Can somebody provide some help?

Comment: Have you tried creating your own format string?

Answer (score 3):

I've used this formatter with style in Swift 3.0 and it works perfectly fine.

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()         
formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX") as Locale!   

//Specified date format
formatter.dateFormat = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"

//Style can be medium, full and short as per the need.
formatter.dateStyle = .medium
let parsedDateString = formatter.date(from: stringDate)
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Were you looking for `dateStyle` ?

```
let formatter = DateFormatter()
formatter.dateStyle = DateFormatter.Style.medium
calendarPicker.startDate = formatter.date(from: t3.text!)
```